# Plotting a world map on R without ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a world map on R but I don't have the version updated for ggplot2. Is there a way of doing it without?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at leaflet (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)

Comment: An outline map? A map with countries coloured by something? For a background to add other things? Using base graphics? How were you trying to do this with ggplot?

Comment: You don't have the up-to-date version of ggplot2? Is there a reason why you can't update it?

Answer (score 7):

You can get an extremely simple world map with:

```
library(maps)
map('world', fill = TRUE, col = 2:8, wrap=c(-180,180) )
```

[image: Simple World map]

And a somewhat better map from the `mapdata` package

```
library(mapdata)
map('worldHires', fill=TRUE, col=2:8)
```

[image: HiRes World]

And just for fun,  here is a version with prettier colors, a blue ocean and cutting out Antarctica.

```
RegHR <- map("worldHires", namesonly=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
map('worldHires', fill=TRUE, col=terrain.colors(6),  bg="#CCEEFF",
    region=RegHR[-grep("Antarctica", RegHR)])
```

[image: Prettier World Map]